# Process data in AWS S3 from EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm wondering what is the best way of processing huge amounts of images stored in  AWS S3 buckets from an Ec2 instance located in the same availability zone.

Should I download the images that I need each time I have to process them and then delete when I'm done, and do the same thing every time I need to do some processing?

Or is there a better way, like mounting the S3 bucket into the EC2 instance? I have seen tools like Fuse for mounting, but I am not sure if this is the best way of processing the data.

Comment: I would recommend to use AWS Lambda triggers to process the images rather using EC2 which is highly salable and managed by amazon for a very reasonable cost compared to EC2. Lambda already has template you can edit.

Also your approach is right storing the images in S3 (Which is the best suitable to store huge amount of images)

Answer (score 1):

First of all. Note that each EC2 instance can be killed, so keep data, and results at reasonable storage - like S3.

If you fetch whole image into memory, and then processing goes. I can't see needs for fetching to disk. On the other hand if image is quite big - you could fetch each part many times. So there is no easy answer, at least with out more information.

You can look at map reduce solutions. How they are  dealing with keeping data close to processing unit. Spark is able to process things in memory.

About mounting resources. There are other options like Elastic File System, or Elastic Block Storage - that can be mounted.